# Custom HTML page in mcrosoft b2c signup

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I need to have my signup page of angular app which should hit microsoft b2c signup service . Please let me know if it is possible. As per the documentation we can apply the css and javascript on top and bottom of the signup page provided by b2c but we cannot perform any customizations on elements inside

Comment: You can customise the B2C rendered elements in the div api tag by targeting their HTML Id. You can inspect the page to find the Ids.

Answer (score 1):

Full and complete instructions of what and how can be customized is described in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview#get-started-with-custom-html-and-css).

Regarding the elements you are talking about, you can create custom attributes in the B2C and use those attributes in the signup policy

Relevant [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui#create-customization-files) reference